# В логе ругается на строку из кода ниже Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD. Может кто сталкивался?

Tags: php

```
    if ( 'POST' !== strtoupper( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: видимо вы или IDE работает через командную строку

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev спасибо попробую

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev а если это PUT или DELETE? А если запрос к скрипту из консоли?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev вот что за стремление везде навтыкать кривых костылей? Такое ощущение что каждый пхпшник не вышел еще из того возраста, когда при уборке мусор заметают под ковер. Мамка не ругается -и ладно. А своего соображения, что мусор как был - таки остался, ещё не выросло. Ошибки надо **исправлять**, а не подавлять. По коду видно, что он ждет метод пост. То есть явно запрашивается по НТТР. То есть метод **должен быть**. И надо разбираться почему

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все верно, но про курл не в тему ;)

Comment: @Ипатьев да, наверное)) убрал)

Comment: Вообще это плагин для wp. В php нe cилён.

Comment: ну тут проблема в том что даже те кто в РНР силен, все равно не понимают что это за фарш такой. если этот код вызывается как обычно - через обращение к сайту, то $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] **должен** присутствовать.

Comment: @Ипатьев ну возможно я не прав. Только в таком случае зачем почти все топовые фреймворки делают проверку, и по умолчанию ставят ``GET``, если ``REQUEST_METHOD`` не проходит isset. Например Symfony ``$request->server->get('REQUEST_METHOD', 'GET')``. Я соглашусь, что это по сути костыль, но я лучше сделаю проверку, чем ловить ошибки подобные (если код вызывает через обращение к сайту). Кстати подобная ошибка ещё часто возникает у Nginx, когда хостинги не так настраивают и никак нельзя повлиять на эти настройки. Поэтому и в популярных CMS стоят такие проверки, если не ошибаюсь.